Why might a court not be allowed to order the sale of home owned by a tenancy of the entirety?
I am reading a case from 1978, Kahn v. Kahn, in which the Court of Appeals in New York debated whether it had the authority to order the sale a couple's home during divorce proceedings.

The principal issue presented on this appeal is whether, in a
matrimonial action, a court may order the sale of real property held
by the parties as tenants by the entirety, even though the marital
relationship has not been legally altered.

I do not understand why the fact that the parties are "tenants by the entirety" would at all matter to whether the court has the power to order the sale of the home. Courts routinely order people to do things that they don't want to do. If I am sued successfully and I don't have the cash to pay, the Court can order me to sell something to satisfy the debt, including my real estate. So why would this be any different?
I don't understand the premise and it's not explained in the judgement. It seems to rely on pre-existing legal knowledge

Tenancy By Entireties explained
Real property is held in tenancy by entirety, in the small minority of U.S. states that recognize that form of ownership, when real property is held in equal joint tenancy by a married couple. Tenancy by entirety property is exempt from the claims of a creditor of one spouse who is not the creditor of the other spouse.
In the time when it arose, this had a practical effect similar to a modern homestead property exemption from creditors, even though it was conceptually different. Normally, at that time, couples often co-owned their residence, but investment or business real property was normally held only in the name of one spouse, usually the husband except in the case of inheritances.
A tenancy by entireties is one of several ways that people who are married can own a particular parcel of real property and applies on a parcel by parcel of real estate basis. Tenancy-in-common (which does not have to be 50-50 and does not include a right of survivorship), or ownership by only one spouse, are other common alternatives for married people to own particular parcels of real estate where tenancy by entireties is an option.
Generally, the only other way that a tenancy by entirety in a particular parcel of real estate can be terminated is when the marriage is dissolved by death, or by a divorce, or when the property is sold or transferred with the mutual voluntary consent of both spouses, which can be denied in either spouse's sole and absolute discretion.
Conceptually, the idea is that tenancy by entirety property belongs to a married couple and can only be alienated, during the marriage, with the mutual consent of both spouses, either directly, or because they mutually borrowed money that was then not paid.
This case in the context of fault based divorce
Kahn v. Kahn was a divorce case filed during the period (which only ended in the year 2010) when New York State had only fault based divorce. The trial court declined to allow the couple to get divorced because marital fault sufficient to allow a divorce was not established. The conclusions that the couple was not entitled to a divorce was undisputed on appeal. This had the de facto effect of converting the divorce case to a legal separation case that did not end the marriage.
Since there wasn't going to be a divorce and the marriage was still intact, and since no joint creditor of the spouses was seeking to enforce a joint debt against the house, it wasn't clear if the court had the authority to end the tenancy by entirety by selling the house, in a mere legal separation case.
The Court of Appeals (which is the highest appellate court in the state courts of New York equivalent to the Supreme Court of most states), resolved that question in Kahn v. Kahn, affirming the common law rule that only the end of a marriage, mutual consent, or a claim of a joint creditor of the spouses could terminate a tenancy by entirety or force a sale of the property.

Yes but why would that prevent a forced sale in a divorce case, especially where one spouse demands it? Why can't the court order the other spouse to consent to the sale?

@ighost Because it wasn't a divorce. The court held that they were not eligible to get divorced.

Thanks for a very thorough explanation. However what I don't understand is why could the court not order the husband in this case to consent to the sale of the home? He's not being ordered to terminate the tenancy by entirety, he's just being ordered to sign off on the sale? Why would the court not be able to do that?

@ighost Because a court order to do something is, by definition, involuntary, and a court cannot order either spouse in an intact marriage to involuntarily terminate the tenancy by entireties. Court ordered consent over a spouse's objection isn't really consent. During a marriage it can only be ended with the voluntary consent of both parties. If either party object to a sale, the court doesn't have the authority to order them to do so. That's the idea at the heart of this kind of property ownership.

I'm confused, because courts order parties to consent all the time. For example, during divorce proceedings, one parent may to sign the children up for school, which requires both parent's consent, and the court can order the non-consenting parent to sign the consent forms. I've seen this happen

@ighost Banish the idea that this is a divorce from your mind. Keep in mind that one spouse can't even get divorced over the objection other the other spouse in a fault based divorce system. If the court could do everything in a legal separation that it could in a divorce, the fault limitation on getting a divorce would be less meaningful. Fault based divorce is a contract based concept of divorce. Similarly, a breaching party can't sue a non-breaching party for breach of contract.

Another confusion: how does ordering the selling of the property end the tenancy of entirety, from a legal perspective? I understand that practically they won't be "tenants" any more because they don't have a house anymore, but the act of selling the house will not dissolve any legal structure between them. It doesn't cause them to become divorced. So what would be the legal problem with just telling them they must both consent to selling the place?

@ighost Put yet another way, tenancy by entirety means that during the marriage, a spouse has an absolute right to refuse to allow the house to be sold.

@igshost "how does ordering the selling of the property end the tenancy of entirety, from a legal perspective?" A tenancy by entirety is specific to specific parcel of real estate and is created with the joint consent of the spouses. If the real estate is converted to money it ceases to exist  (also, if the house is sold, half of the proceeds are subject to the creditors of a single spouse and not just to the claims of joint creditors). Imagine that wife's business failed and she is successfully sued for big $$, her husband can't lose his house because of that.

"Keep in mind that one spouse can't even get divorced over the objection other the other spouse in a fault based divorce system." Also, when the divorce case was started being married had more legal consequences: the marital rape exemption, the inability of a wife to get a credit card without a cosigner, immunity from most non-divorce lawsuits by the other spouse, immunity from some other crimes by the spouse, a right of a husband to physically discipline a wife, etc. Abortion wasn't legal.

Ok thanks I got it now. I thought a couple only had one "tenancy of the entirety" and it applied to any land they owned. But that seems to be a misunderstanding. It sounds like a couple can have multiple TotEs and each one comes into existence when the couple acquires property, and if the property is removed from them somehow, the TotE evaporates as well

@igshost Correct, TBE is specific to a particular parcel of real property. There could be more than one, there could be none. It is an alternative to tenancy in common between spouses or non-spouses, or to joint tenancy with right of survivorship between non-spouses, or to ownership of real property by one spouse only, or to a life estate in one spouse and a remainder interest in the other, etc.
